# How to access derived class properties from base class instance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection

I have the following code which I can't access or change:

```
class A{
}

class B:A{
    string name;
    int age;
    string desc;
}

class C:A{
    string name;
    int age;
    string desc;
}
```

I need to find a way to write a function that assigns values to instances of B and C. the naive way would be to write two functions. one for each class.

```
void myFunc(B b){
    b.name = "some_name";
    b.age = 27;
    b.desc = "some_desc";
}

void myFunc(C c){
    c.name = "some_name";
    c.age = 27;
    c.desc = "some_desc";
}
```

Is there a way to write one generic function that those the job?
of-course those classes are only examples. In the real world there are many classes deriving from the base class and each class has many members.

Comment: The base class knows nothing about its children.

Comment: If they have the same name and are the same type, why are they in the derived classes instead of the base class? Isn't the whole idea of inheritance not that you don't duplicate things like this? Alternatively, define interfaces and implement them in your classes. Then you can set those properties based on the interfaces the classes implement.

Comment: "I have the following code _which I can't access or change_"

Comment: You added some interesting tags so let me adress them, you can use reflection which is bad idea as simple changes like renaming fields will break your code and Parent should have no knowledge of it's children. Generics are good when you want to write same logic that operates on different types (example are Lists, Dictionaries etc.) so in this case it is unnecesary.  Best solution, as other have pointed out would be  some kind of "base class" or use of interfaces.

Comment: Actually you can do nothing. You cannot even write the functions you set as an example, as all the properties are PRIVATE.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Well, since you can't change the base classes I can only attribute it to bad design, you have 3 options: using `object` bypassing type safety and using pattern matching switch, or just retyping it yourself. Code multiple overloading functions. Lastly using reflection, it's risk based on how much can the underlaying class change in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find several ways to do this.
For example you can use an extension method for the type: A
And use reflection to set fields in it.

Like this:

```
public static class ClassExtensions
{
    public static void SetProperties(this A a, string name, int age, string desc)
    {
        Type type = a.GetType();
        type.GetField("name")?.SetValue(a, name);
        type.GetField("age")?.SetValue(a, age);
        type.GetField("desc")?.SetValue(a, desc);
    }
}
```

Here is how it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uR3bA

Or just use dynamic like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var b = new B();
    SetValues(b, "yes", 5, "ok");

    var c = new C();
    SetValues(c, "no", 10, "not ok");
}

public static void SetValues(dynamic theClass, string name, int age, string desc)
{
    theClass.name = name;
    theClass.age = age;
    theClass.desc = desc;
}
```

Note: I'm assuming the fields or properties will be public, not private.

Comment: Exercise: what's going to happen if someone calls those methods with a `class D : A {}`? Notice that `D` also inherits `A`, but doesn't define any properties.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Of course these solutions will not make everything perfect. I wasn't suggesting so also. Because the foundation of what we are working with is broken. But calling like `b.SetProperties("yes", 5, "ok")` looks the most natural in the code. But anyway I've added Null-conditional just so it won't crash. Meaning, if you pass D, it will do nothing now.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious: why not using `Automapper`? It uses a `convention-based` approach, and when that's not enough, you can write the mapping code yourself and inject it.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good design. *If* you can in any way change it, strongly consider doing so, but if you can't, here's what you can do.

You don't need Reflection for this. [Downcasting](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) will do the job:

```
void MyMethod(A a)
{
    if (a is B b)
    {
        b.name = "some_name";
        b.age = 27;
        b.desc = "some_desc";        
    }

    if (a is C c)
    {
        c.name = "some_name";
        c.age = 27;
        c.desc = "some_desc";
    }
}
```

Since `A` is an unsealed base class, other derived classes could exist (`class D : A` etc.), but since `MyMethod` doesn't return anything, passing any other subtype as an argument is simply going to be a no-op.

Comment: @Shay said there might be many classes, so probably this approach will result in a gigantic mapping method. At this point wouldn't it be better to have some kind of MappingProvider and register the individual mapping functions in the Composition Root?
(btw hi Mark, great fan here)

Comment: @DavidGuida I admit that I missed that sentence  There's clearly going to be some threshold where downcasting isn't viable, and where Reflection is a better option. The benefit of downcasting is that it still offers compile-time safety, which you completely throw overboard with Reflection, so exactly where that tipping point is depends (as usual) on circumstances.

Comment: oh absolutely! To me, Reflection was never going to be an option. I was suggesting to create specific Mapper classes for every case (or even Func<>), register them in the Composition Root and then invoke them via a Mapping Factory registered as singleton. 
Then if you want to use Reflection in the mapper code, help yourself :D